# How do I send to multiple emails after getting the email from query results?

Tags: powershell

I have a table where each record has an email address and a date.  I need to do a query through the table where if the date is less than one day then I need to send to the email address that is associated with that record.

I set up the email sending which is working for tests but I have been failing to retrieve the information I need and sending to multiple addresses.  Each row of the query will have an email address that needs to be added to the recipient list.  Could someone please help?

Here is the code I have so far.

I have already tried an if statement where if true then send retrieve the email from records and add to the recipient list

```
$Username = "moc";
$Password = "xxxxxx";

function Send-ToEmail([string]$email){

    $message = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage;
    $message.From = "moc@company.com";
    $message.To.Add($email);
    $message.Subject = "New Items Item Request";
    $message.Body = "You have new items in the Request App";

    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("hq", "host");
    $smtp.EnableSSL = $false;
    $smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
    $smtp.send($message);
    write-host "Mail Sent" ; 
 }
Send-ToEmail  -email  "test@market.com","test@market.com";
```

Again I have been able to send emails with the above code to a test email address, but I am having difficulty retrieving the addresses from each row and adding them to the recipient list.

Comment: Email addresses need to be separated by a semi-colon.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, do you want `Send-ToEmail` to support sending the message to a list of email addresses?

Comment: Yes I do.  Once I query the emails from a sql query I would like to add this list to the recipients so that they all get the same email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, modify your function signature to accept an array of email addresses:

```
function Send-ToEmail([string[]]$emailAddresses){
```

then to add, iterate over all these addresses, adding each one:

```
$emailAddresses | foreach {$message.To.Add($_)}
```